# Реализация механизма полиморфизма в Java

Tags: java, jvm, полиморфизм

Что из себя представляет механизм полиморфизма в Java и как он работает? Если это зависит от реализации конкретной JVM, то хотелось бы увидеть это на примере какой-нибудь JVM, например HotSpot.

Для уточнения, в С++ полиморфизм реализуется за счет таблицы виртуальных функций для каждого класса, указатель на которую неявно хранится в каждом экземпляре класса. А как это сделано в Java?

Comment: Если вас интересуют именно функции, то в java они все виртуальные.

Comment: Вопрос скорее про то, как осуществляется выбор виртуальной функции во время исполнения программы? Как выбирается какой метод вызвать, текущего класса или базового? Там это тоже сделано за счет таблицы методов?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Полиморфизм метода, определённого в классе, достигается за счёт выбора по таблице виртуальных методов примерно как в C++. То есть накладные расходы на вызов — это взять у объекта classword (который записан в его заголовке), добавить к нему известное заранее смещение и вызвать метод по указанному адресу.

Полиморфизм метода, определённого в интерфейсе, достигается более сложным путём: в структуре описания класса ищется запись, относящаяся к данному интерфейсу, и в ней уже ищется нужный метод. То есть, скажем,

```
public static <T> T getFirst(List<T> list) { return list.get(0); }

public static <T> T getFirst(AbstractList<T> list) { return list.get(0); }
```

Первый случай *может* оказаться медленнее, потому что мы вызываем метод интерфейса. Хотя метод один и тот же, но разница есть. Даже в байткоде две разные инструкции — invokeinterface и invokevirtual.

JIT-компилятор HotSpot агрессивно использует технику девиртуализации. Естественно в обычный статический вызов превратится вызов final-метода или метода final-класса. Также если runtime-таблица типов говорит, что данный метод нигде не переопределён, вызов будет статическим:

```
public static <T> T getFirst(ArrayList<T> list) { 
    return <static call> list.get(0); 
}
```

Хотя `ArrayList` не final-класс и метод `get` тоже не final, если мы знаем, что он не переопределён на данный момент ни в одном загруженном классе, мы можем сделать вызов статическим. Если будет загружен новый класс, который нарушит это условие, JIT-компилятор перекомпилирует этот метод.

Если есть варианты, используется профиль типов. К примеру, если этот код уже выполнялся 5000 раз и из них в 4990 случаях вызывался конкретный метод `ArrayList.get`, то JIT-компилированный код станет примерно таким:

```
public static <T> T getFirst(List<T> list) { 
    if(list.getClass() == ArrayList.class) {
        return <static call> ((ArrayList<T>)list).get(0);
    }
    // обновить профиль типов
    return list.get(0); 
}
```

Проверка `list.getClass() == ArrayList.class` весьма быстрая — это достать classword (по скорости как прочитать поле объекта) и сравнить с константой (на момент JIT-компиляции точно известен classword для класса ArrayList). Branch-prediction тоже хорошо отработает, если условие в подавляющем большинстве случаев выполняется.

Если из 5000 вызовов было 3000 `ArrayList` и 1990 `LinkedList`, код будет примерно таким:

```
public static <T> T getFirst(List<T> list) { 
    if(list.getClass() == ArrayList.class) {
        return <static call> ((ArrayList<T>)list).get(0);
    } else if(list.getClass() == LinkedList.class) {
        return <static call> ((LinkedList<T>)list).get(0);
    }
    // обновить профиль типов
    return list.get(0); 
}
```

Это биморфный вызов. Если же популярных вариантов было больше двух, то тогда уж вызов останется честным виртуальным.

Разумеется, если вы в одном методе вызываете несколько методов неизвестного объекта, переданного параметром (или в цикле вызываете метод много раз), то тип проверяться будет только один раз.

Если вызов удалось девиртуализовать (хотя бы в биморфный вариант), то дальше агрессивно применяется инлайнинг (видал своими глазами как в один метод инлайнилось штук 70 других на глубину вызовов до 8-9: в первый инлайнится второй, в него третий и т. д.). Инлайнинг открывает дорогу к тонне других оптимизаций.

Как вы уже поняли, первоначально код выполняется во-первых, медленнее, а во-вторых в режиме профилирования. То есть при каждом вызове метода не просто происходит вызов, но и обновляется таблица статистики, где указывается, какой конкретно класс тут был. Когда статистика собрана, метод перекомпилируется с учётом неё. При этом если есть быстрая и медленная ветка, то медленная будет обновлять статистику дальше. Например, если сценарий использования программы поменялся, то метод может быть снова перекомпилирован.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый и подробный ответ!
Остался еще небольшой вопрос по поводу таблицы виртуальных методов - где хранится указатель на нее?

Comment: @AndreyArzhannikov, сама таблица хранится в структуре, описывающей класс, а указатель на эту структуру (classword) хранится в заголовке каждого объекта (что-то вроде обязательного скрытого поля).

Comment: еще раз благодарю)