# Переопределенные методы в Java

Tags: java, ооп

Допустим есть класс `A` и наследуемый от него класс `B`.

И у `А`, и у `B` есть метод `get()`, который в первом случае возвращает переменную из класса `А`, а во втором из класса `B`. И есть ссылочная переменная `ptr` класса `A`.
Как будет работать такой код?

```
A ptr = new A();  
ptr.get(); // это выполнится  
ptr = new B(); // ссылочная переменная суперкласса может  
               // указывать на объект подкласса, если я все правильно понял.    
ptr.get(); // тут будет вызван метод get() класса В
           // т.к. ссылка на объект В. 
           // Но сам метод берет приватную переменную из объекта В. 
           // А суперкласс о ней не знает, и для него она не существует.".
```

Как это работает? Или я что-то не верно понял?

Comment: Гляньте мой ответ тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/491263/%d0%92%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be-%d0%b0%d0%b1%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%80%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc-%d0%b2-java/491273#491273

Comment: Если вы хотите знать, как это работает на низком уровне, то прочтите о [таблице виртуальных методов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2) и, например, ответ на [этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454960/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%B2-java/455003) от самого Тагира Валеева

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Определение переменной `ptr` класса `A` ограничивает доступные для объекта методы интерфейсом класса `A` (перечнем методов с их параметрами и возвращаемыми значениями). Т.е. нельзя будет вызвать методы, добавленные в наследниках.

При переопределении метода `C get()` в классе-наследнике `B` мы имеем доступ ко всем приватным полям `B`. При вызове метода будет возвращена копия ссылки на объект из приватного поля. При этом поле останется недоступным: обращение к приватному полю `ptr.reference` не скомпилируется ни для суперкласса, ни для наследника.

Возьмём следующие классы:

```
class A {
    private C reference=new C();
    C get() {
         return reference;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    private D reference=new D();
    @Override
    C get() {
        return reference;
    }
}

class C {}

class D extends C {}
```

Выполним следующий код:

```
A ptr=new A();
System.out.println(ptr.get() instanceof C);
ptr= new B();
System.out.println(ptr.get() instanceof C);
System.out.println(ptr.get() instanceof D);
```

Получим

```
true
true
true
```

Кстати, при переопределении метода в качестве возвращаемого значения можно использовать наследника класса из родительского определения, т.е. в классе `B` можно написать `D get()`. В данном примере результат не изменится.

Answer (score 2):

Это полиморфизм, объект класса `A` определяет только возвращаемый тип объекта (предоставляет интерфейс), а реализация полностью лежит в классе `B`. Когда будет вызван метод `get`  по сути просто вызовется метода класса `B`, а компилятор не будет ругаться, потому что сигнатура методов будет полностью совпадать.

Comment: Это я понял. Но get возвращает переменную из объекта  В, которую класс А по-сути не видит. Ошибки не будет? Метод найдет переменную из класса В?

Comment: Ошибки не будет. Опять же, реализация полностью в классе `B`, класс `A` в данном случае вообще ни причём