# Можно ли сделать имплементируемый метод статическим?

Tags: java

Можно ли сделать имплементируемый метод в java статическим? если нет, то почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ответ:**

Если я вас правильно понял, и речь идет об абстрактном методе (абстрактного класса или интерфейса), который вы хотите переопределить в наследнике, то - нет, это невозможсно.

**Пояснение:**

Статические методы не попадают в [таблицу виртуальных методов (VMT)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2), поэтому не могут быть переопределены в наследниках.

**Что почитать:**

Можете прочитать [здесь](https://habr.com/ru/company/otus/blog/467197/) и [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/455003/200756).

Comment: а можно ли как то выйти из этой ситуации?

Comment: @IanReed например, использовать нестатический метод, который будет реализован каким-то вашим классом, который будет представлен в единственном экземпляре (паттерн singleton).

Comment: даже так не получится избежать создание инстанса(

Comment: @IanReed дак в стом и суть, что инстанс будет, но он будет ровно один.

А почему вам так важно переопределить статический метод? Почему вы сразу не можете статическим методом воспользоваться без переопределения в наследнике?

Comment: могу и так, но тогда заканичвается мое понимание смысла интерфейсов)

Comment: Просто обычно статические методы - это что-то утилитное, что не нужно переопределять в наследниках.
Обычно они находятся в утилитных классах (final классах (наследников от которых нельзя создать) и с приватным конструктором (чтобы не могли создать их инстанс, т.к. это не имеет смысла)).

Comment: @IanReed А если все же логика зависит от реализации, то используются интерфейсы с реализациями, предоставляемыми в рамках инстансов наследников. Обычно, для получения инстанса реализации того или иного интерфейса используется паттерн factory (в factory классе на основании ваших настроек конфигурации (например, из properties файла или env'ов) и решается какой инстанс наследника создать), поэтому с инстансом наследниках работа всегда происходит как с интерфейсом, чтобы не было завязки на реализацию (чтобы вы в factory всегда могли подменить инстанс реализации).

Comment: ох... слишком много информации для меня... можно задать вопрос не по теме? почему при использовании синглтона не получается переопределить метод?

Comment: @IanReed должно получаться, покажите пример кода. Можете написать его, например, вот [здесь](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_java_compiler). А так, для примера, основная идея Spring Core - это Dependency Injection (внедрение зависимостей) - это когда вы у класса определяете поле интерфейсного типа, где-то в прокте создаете класс, реализующий этот интерфейс и помечаете его соответствующей аннотацией, и spring сам вам set'ил в поле реализацию.

Comment: ой, я ошибся, просто ошибка в синтаксисе, странно что idea не подсказала

Comment: в любом случае спасибо, что уделили время!